# Android Open GL - glDrawArrays - optimized out?

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This is simple to describe but has me baffled. It needs another set of eyes. As usual I expect it's something either stupid or something everyone knows about except me.  Also, as I rarely have to ask a question (someone's almost always asked it before), I expect I will have made some faux pas in the format.

The code below draws an object using a texture written to in a two-pass render-to-texture texture[0]. It then does a glReadPixels which is used in some other logic then switches to another texture which contains text and overwrites the central part of the object (it's actually a functional Open GL button).  The same problem exists with or without the glReadPixels

So. If I uncomment the two lines in the first section it works visually as expected using texture[1] (functionally this is not what I want). If I comment the lines out it works visually as expected with texture[0] but the final glDrawArrays which is supposed to overwrite the central face with the text in texture[1] appears to do nothing as if it's been optimized out. So I have two pieces of apparently identical code which work as expected in one context but not the other. The switch mButtonFaceHandle must work as it operates correctly in the first instance as does texture[1]

```java
//This a switch in the shader unrelated to the texture
GLES20.glUniform1i(mButtonFaceHandle, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
//Draw bezels
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,0, (numVertices/3)-6);
//GLES20.glUniform1i(mButtonFaceHandle, 1);
//GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
//Draw central face
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,(numVertices/3)-6, 6);

//glReadPixels omitted for clarity

//This a switch in the shader unrelated to the texture
GLES20.glUniform1i(mButtonFaceHandle, 1);
//Redraw central face using texture[1]
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,(numVertices/3)-6, 6);
glioGLRenderer.checkGlError("end");
```

Comment: Unrelated to the original question, but you _really_ don't want to do a glReadPixels in your main render loop. Ever. You flush and stall the entire rendering pipeline.

Comment: I know this, but this is an exercise in creating active buttons in an Open GL window and will not be rendered in a main loop.

Answer (score 0):

Depth Test. Disabling depth test before drawing and re-enabling afterwards fixed this problem.  I need to satisfy myself why this is. Both textures are drawn to the same vertices, quite why one would have depth precedent over the other I'm not sure. I'll report back when I know what's going on.

Comment: Precedence depends on your depth test function set via `glDepthFunc()`; `GL_LESS` would keep the first draw, `GL_LEQUAL` would keep the second.

Comment: Excellent. That works. Now I know what's going on and another string to my bow.  There's always something new with with this stuff. Thanks.